# Forwarding of a specific port

Tags: linux, iptables, forwarding

I tried forwarding a specific ip:port to a specific ip:port on a linux machine. I used iptables with the following command:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 10.0.2.5 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 69.31.21.42:80
```

10.0.2.5 is an arbitrary address that I chose to see if the command works, and 69.31.21.42 is an address of a public web site.
I then verified that the the forwarding worked: I ran `nmap -p 80 10.0.2.5` and got a positive result. Very good so far. However, I then tried running `nmap -p 81 10.0.2.5`, and also got a positive result. That's not what I expected, as I wanted port 80 only to be forwarded. I ran `iptables -t nat -L` and noticed that indeed, the entire 10.0.2.5 host is mapped to 69.31.21.42:80:

```
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source     destination
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere   ip-10-0-2-5.ec2.internal  tcp dpt:http to:69.31.21.42:80
```

What's missing in my iptables command? Why isn't `--dport` working?

Comment: Firstly, you say that "*the entire 10.0.2.15 host is mapped to 69.31.21.42:80*" but you offer in support of that `iptables` output with a hostname of `ip-10-0-2-5.ec2.internal`, which is probably **not** `10.0.2.15`.  Secondly, we're missing important output like port restrictions; try using `iptables -L -n -v`, **not** just `iptables -L`, and update that rule above.

Comment: Edited to replace 10.0.2.15 by 10.0.2.5, which seems to be the intent.

Comment: That shouldn't happen. I tried replicating your problem with the exact statements, but different IP-addreses, and I got a "No route to host" error. Because I chosed an IP-address on my local network which is not in use. Is it possible that you're using an IP-address of a server which exists *and* has a service running on tcp/81?

Comment: @MadHatter - I ran iptables -L -n -v and the output doesn't even contain 10.0.2.5... However I not use a different machine and the output of iptables -t nat -L is:
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             ip-10-0-2-15.ec2.internal  tcp dpt:2553 to:10.0.0.4:2554
This seems ok, right? Maybe the problem was machine specific?

Comment: @AlexanderJanssen - the IP address I'm using is definitely not of a server that's already running. I made sure that the same nmap command fails before I run the iptables command, and succeeds later.

Comment: You are pretty clearly **still** not using `-n`.  Detail is important.  Precision is important.  Please update your question as requested; if you have output from other servers that seems relevant, do add that **as well** - but please don't change the substance of your question mid-stream!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `POSTROUTING` chain for do what you want to do.

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 10.0.2.5 --dport 80 -j SNAT --to 69.31.21.42:80
```

man iptables

```
and POSTROUTING (for altering packets as they  are  about  to  go
                  out)
```

Answer (score -2):

First of all please know that it's not possible to forward TCP IP:Port to another IP:Port. This is only possible with UDP and there's a separate Perl script for that.

Yes you can forward an IP directly to another machine, not a specific port.

Comment: Sorry, Asad; are you saying that you cannot DNAT TCP traffic destined to one port, to another port on the same, or a different, server?  Because if you are, that's simply wrong.